# Angular translate core - updating the translations from http request

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I've added the [@ngx-translate/core](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core), inside a http-request I get dropdown values. Those values are then added to a translation language object using the method:

```js
translate.setTranslation('en', {
  HELLO: 'hello {{value}}'
});
```

Is there any way to merge this newly created object with the originally loaded translations. I'm using the provided custom loader, is there a way to reuse it to load new translations.

```js
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

Comment: You can use an interceptor to intercept the response , Modify/ append data and use it. Or you can create a customer loader for the same

Comment: @Vikas I'm using the provided custom loader, is there any way to use it to merge the new translations into the asset file previously loaded?